# Bash scripting || sed command

Tags: bash, sed, user-input

I am trying to add # in front of a line if string gets a match.
String will be read by user.
Direct `sed` command well for me but when is user read command then it throws error:

```
server cust01-stg01-ins01-wfm13-bck-610358970-22.int.stg.mykronos.com:80 resolve max_fails=0;
server cust01-stg01-ins01-wfm13-bck-610358970-25.int.stg.mykronos.com:80 resolve max_fails=0;
server cust01-stg01-ins01-wfm13-bck-610358970-21.int.stg.mykronos.com:80 resolve max_fails=0;
server cust01-stg01-ins01-wfm13-bck-610358970-23.int.stg.mykronos.com:80 resolve max_fails=0;
server cust01-stg01-ins01-wfm13-bck-610358970-24.int.stg.mykronos.com:80 resolve max_fails=0;
```

Now suppose user want to comment line with matching character `"cust01-stg01-ins01-wfm13-bck-610358970-22"` then below output is expected

```
#server cust01-stg01-ins01-wfm13-bck-610358970-22.int.stg.mykronos.com:80 resolve max_fails=0;
server cust01-stg01-ins01-wfm13-bck-610358970-25.int.stg.mykronos.com:80 resolve max_fails=0;
server cust01-stg01-ins01-wfm13-bck-610358970-21.int.stg.mykronos.com:80 resolve max_fails=0;
server cust01-stg01-ins01-wfm13-bck-610358970-23.int.stg.mykronos.com:80 resolve max_fails=0;
server cust01-stg01-ins01-wfm13-bck-610358970-24.int.stg.mykronos.com:80 resolve max_fails=0;


sudo sed -i "/cust01-stg01-ins01-wfm13-bck-610358970-23/s/^/#/" wfm_backend_nginx.state
```

this works well for me but when I am trying below command then it is throwing error.

```
[root@cust01-stg01-ins01-wfm13-bck-ilb1-610358970 tmp]# cat ilb_commnet.sh
#!/bin/bash -xe
sudo read -p "enter host_name :" Host
sudo sed -i -e "/${Host}/s/^/#/" /tmp/wfm_backend_nginx.state
```

Output is :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

Comment: Please edit your post. Please read about markdown editing. Please put code snippets inside code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> sudo read -p "enter host_name :" Host
> ```

`sudo` runs a separate process, that will read the input and save it into `Host`. Then the process will exit, destroying the whole environment with the read value.

Remove `sudo` - read the value in current process.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sudo` is completely crazy here. You are running `read` in a privileged subshell, which then exits and takes the variable with it before you can use it for anything.

... Actually `sudo read` is simply a syntax error because `sudo` can't run a shell built-in.  It tries to look for `/usr/bin/read`, `/bin/read` etc but doesn't find anything.

```
bash$ sudo read -p hello
sudo: read: command not found
```

Even without the `sudo`, your code should probably examine the variable before attempting to pass it to a privileged command.  Maybe something like

```sh
#!/bin/bash -xe
while true; do
    read -p "Enter host name: " Host
    case $Host in
      *[!A-Za-z0-9]*) echo "$0: Invalid characters in host name" >&2;;
      *) break
    esac
done
sudo sed -i -e "/${Host}/s/^/#/" /tmp/wfm_backend_nginx.state
```